# Horizontal Recycler View with dynamic content in Scroll View. When the content is more than the viewport, vertical scroll is not working

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a Horizontal `Recycler View` in a `Scroll View`.

The content of the items in the Recycler View is dynamic, meaning that their height is different.

When the content exceed the height of the viewport, the content is clipped at the bottom.

The layout of the Recycler View:

```
<androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:fillViewport="true">
  
  <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
      android:id="@+id/rv"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:nestedScrollingEnabled="true"
      android:orientation="horizontal"
      app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager" />

  </RelativeLayout>


</androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

I have tried many different solutions:

1. Set different `ViewGroup`s as the Nested Scroll View child
2. Set `android:nestedScrollingEnabled` to true/false
3. Tried with ConstraintLayout and `0dp` heights and using `app:layout_constrainedHeight="true"`

And other than I cannot recall.

The layout of the item looks as such:

```
  <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:padding="30dp">

    <TextView
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      app:layout_constrainedHeight="true"
      android:background="@android:color/black"
      android:padding="20dp"
      android:text="@{text}"
      android:textColor="@android:color/white"
      app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

  </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

And a demonstration of the issue:

At the end of the dummy text there should be a `[END]`.
In the beginning it's visible and after a while not.

https://youtu.be/iX1jhihgNx0